# Django where in queryset with comma separated slug in url

Tags: python, django

I have a Post Model

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150,null=True,blank=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

So in view I need to query all the posts with specific category for example
This is the url http://example.com/?category=slug1,slug2 or http://example.com/?category=1,2 - PK or slug will be used

**views.py**

```
class PostList(TemplateView):
    ...
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        categories = request.GET.get('category')
        post_list = Post.objects().filter(categories__in=categories)
    ...
```

The above view throws error as `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','` because of passing comma separated strings, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma separated you're going to have to do this by hand:

`categories = request.GET.get('category').split(',')`

The more Django way to do this it so change your query string to be

`?category=slug1&category=slug2`.

Then you could use

`categories = request.GET.getlist('category')`